# Trying to pack a uint16 into 2 bytes of a byte array C#

Tags: c#, networking, byte, arrays

I have to send a packet that has packet structure of:

```
1 byte padding (0x0)
2 byte (uint16) opcode
1 byte padding (0x0)
x bytes raw struct
```

So I need a way to put a uint16 into my byte array.

```
byte[] rawData = new byte[x+4];
rawData[0] = 0;
rawData[1] = (uint16-highbyte?) opcode;
rawData[2] = (uint16-lowbyte?) opcode;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rawData[1] = (byte) (opcode >> 8);
rawData[2] = (byte) opcode;
```

The `>>` is a signed right shift operator. It will shift bits to the right, repeating the leftmost bit at the left, to keep the signed two-complement number valid.

For example:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  = 0x0301
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

0x0301 >> 8 =

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  = 0x0003
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The `(byte)` cast will keep only the lower 8 bits of your data. So:

```
                                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
(byte) (0x0301 >> 8) =          | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  = 0x03
                                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

                                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
(byte) 0x0301 =                 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  = 0x01
                                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Always best to explain your answers a little

Comment: Especially the part where you always write 0 in rawData[1].

Answer (score 0):

here's another approach.

```
fixed(short* ps = &rawData[1]){
    *ps = opcode;
}
```

GOOD LUCK!

**Update**

Both of these produce the same result.

```
byte[] rawData = new byte[4];
short opcode = 16859;

fixed (void* ps = &rawData[1]) {
    *(short*)ps = opcode;
}

Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));

byte[] opBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(opcode);

rawData = new byte[4];
rawData[1] = opBytes[0];
rawData[2] = opBytes[1];

Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
```

Comment: Endian-ness is not a detail that can be ignored here.

Comment: A packet needs to be portable between programs running on different platforms with different endianness. So native endian code like yours is a bad idea. The OP's example uses big-endian, so your code doesn't match it even if you assume that the code only runs on little endian systems.

Comment: good point CodesInChaos. we were writing our posts at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

C# has things for doing this already....

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(opcode);
```

Documented here :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66.aspx

Comment: Keith, you mean .NET has them, not C#. C# has nothing like it.